# How do I add 3rd level of dropdowns to wp_nav_menu array?

Tags: menus, navigation, walker

How do I get 3rd level to show?

```
<?php
    wp_nav_menu(
        array(
            'theme_location'  => 'primary',
            'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
            'container_id'    => 'navbarNavDropdown',
            'menu_class'      => 'navbar-nav ml-auto',
            'fallback_cb'     => '',
            'menu_id'         => 'main-menu',
            'depth'           => 2,
            'walker'          => new Understrap_WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker(),
        )
    );
?>
```

[image]

Comment: Normally the problem here is CSS, any answer will be 100% CSS, it should require any WordPress knowledge other than an inspection of the HTML classes on the `ul`/`li` tags. However, your code uses `Understrap_WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker` which is an unknown class, which means any answer you get here probably won't be usable. You'll need to contact understrap support or abandon using that navwalker

Comment: First, I'd try changing the `'depth'` argument from `2` to `3`.

Comment: @PatJ tried that to no avail

Comment: @RLM This post might be helpful if you haven't checked it already: https://davidstockdalescrapcode.co.uk/understrap-sub-menu-depth